# Change values on x and y axis on a graph

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to change the values on a graph, but I don't have the initial data, means I have just the graph. Any idea?

Comment: You don't have the source data for a graph? How is the graph drawn then? Changing the limits of x & y axes can be done by clicking on the axis ... Format Axis / and then modifying them in Axis options category.

Comment: Yes its merely a picture, I don't have the data. When I go to format axis, it doesn't allow me to type the values I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the image as a graphic file (.JPG, .PNG, .GIF, etc.) or a hardcopy that you could scan to produce a graphic file, there is a wide variety of graph digitising software packages that you could use to retrieve the original data points, which you could then re-plot any way you liked.

There is a [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converting_scanned_graphs_to_data) article that provides references to a number of packages, another [list](http://web.archive.org/web/20100728095151/http://www.ccp14.ac.uk/solution/hardcopy2data.htm) of software alternatives for the same task and a [CNET](http://download.cnet.com/Digitize-It/3000-20415_4-10489008.html) review of still another package that carries out this task.

Of the various packages that I've used over time to do this, the one I used most recently was [WinDig](http://www.unige.ch/sciences/chifi/cpb/windig.html) though it is getting pretty old -- it is still a 16-bit Windows application -- so I wouldn't necessarily recommend that one.